# How to get back the original string after decompressing - Zlib

Tags: javascript, gzip, zlib, compression

I am trying to compress and decompress the string using `Zlib`. Here is the [JS](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/master/bin/zlib_and_gzip.min.js) file I'm using to compress and decompress.

**Compression code:**

```
compress_string = function () {

   var string = document.getElementById("input_value").value;

   var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(string);
   var compressed = deflate.compress();

   var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed));

   var elem = document.getElementById("input_value");
   elem.value = b64encoded;

   var elemLabel = document.getElementById("zlsize");
   elemLabel.value = ("Size of sample is: " + string.length) + " " + ("Compressed Value: " + b64encoded + " Size: " + b64encoded.length);

}
```

After compressing I'm setting the compressed value back to the `input_value` text field.

**Decompression Code:**

```
decompress_string = function () {

   var string = document.getElementById("input_value").value;

   var compressData = new Uint8Array(atob(string).split("").map(function(c) { return c.charCodeAt(0); }))

   var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressData);
   var plain = inflate.decompress();

   var elem = document.getElementById("input_value");
   elem.value = btoa(plain);

   var elemLabel = document.getElementById("zlsize");
   elemLabel.value = ("Size of compressed string is: " + string.length) + " " + ("Decompressed Value: " + plain + " Size: " + plain.length);
}
```

I'm trying to compress below sample string:

```
<xml><username>myusername</username><password>mypassword</password></xml>
```

**Size of sample is: 73**

**Compressed Value:** `eJxNibEJAAAMg/7/OjoEdCjGAoAnmqg6fF8T7QMfCxxR`

**Size: 44**

When trying to decompress the above compressed string, I'm getting an object of `Uint8Array` as below:

**Size of compressed string is: 44**

**Decompressed Value:** `[object Uint8Array]`

**Size: 70**

While trying to  convert the object `Uint8Array` to string using `btoa()`, the output is like below:

```
W29iamVjdCBVaW50OEFycmF5XQ==
```

*Question:* **How to get the original string?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is text encoding.

Uint8Array is a binary representation of something, and strings can be written in many formats. You need to stick to one, and convert using that.

I've chosen UTF-8 in this example, using this [library](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding)

```
function compress(input){
    var binaryconverter = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
    var binary = binaryconverter.encode(input);
    var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(binary);
    var compressed = deflate.compress();
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, compressed));
}

function decompress(b64encoded){
    var compressed = new Uint8Array(atob(b64encoded).split("").map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0);}));
    var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressed);
    var binary = inflate.decompress();
    var binaryconverter = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    return binaryconverter.decode(binary);
}

var input = '<xml><username>myusername</username><password>mypassword</password></xml>';
var b64encoded = compress(input);
var output = decompress(b64encoded);
alert(output);
```

So, when encoding, I first convert the string to the binary representation of the text in UTF-8 format, then I'm using ZLib to compress, and then again this is converted to a base64 string for ease of transfer.

To decompress, you do the inverse thing: first decode the base64 string, then ZLib to inflate and finally again we convert binary to string using UTF-8

Comment: the library needs only `encoding.js` since we use UTF-8 only.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) appear to suggest `plain` (input) of type `Array.<number> or Uint8Array`

```
    // plain = Array.<number> or Uint8Array
    var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(plain);
    var compressed = deflate.compress();
```

at OP , `var string` appear to be type `string` , see

```
   var string = document.getElementById("input_value").value;
   var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(string);
```

To retrieve the `text` value from compressed , `base64` formatted string , below ;  first , map `var string` to `.charCodeAt()` `number` , returning array of `number`s representing text characters ; second , push `.charCodeAt()` numbers to map array ; third, call `window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(escape(compressed[i])))` on each item within array of `charCodeAt()` values , pushed to same map array; fourth , decode `base64encoded` string in `for` loop , calling `String.fromCharCode(plain[i])` on decompressed [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) , returning original input `string`.

Try

```
var elem = document.getElementById("input_value")
    , elemLabel = document.getElementById("zlsize")
    , compress = document.getElementById("compress")
    , decompress = document.getElementById("decompress")
    , b64map = []
    , _b64encoded
    , b64encoded
    , _string
    , string
    , _plain
    , compressData;

    function compress_string () {
        string = elem.value;
        _string = [].slice.call(string).map(function (value, key) {
            return value.charCodeAt(0)
        });
        var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(_string);
        var compressed = deflate.compress();
        for (var i = 0; i < compressed.length; i++) {
            b64map.push([compressed[i]
                , window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(escape(compressed[i])))])
        };
        _b64encoded = b64map.map(function (value, key) {
            return value[1]
        });
        b64encoded = _b64encoded.join("");
        elem.value = b64encoded;
        elemLabel.innerText = ("Size of sample is: " 
                              + string.length) + " " + ("Compressed Value: " 
                              + b64encoded + " Size: " + b64encoded.length)
    };

    function decompress_string () {
        string = elem.value;
        elem.value = "";
        compressData = _b64encoded.map(function (value, key) {                      
            return new RegExp(value).test(string) ? b64map[key][0] : null
        });

        compressData = new Uint8Array(compressData);
        var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressData);

        var plain = inflate.decompress();
        b64map = b64encoded = [];
        _plain = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < plain.length; i++) {
            _plain += String.fromCharCode(plain[i])
        };
        elem.value = _plain;
        elemLabel.innerText = ("Size of compressed string is: " 
                              + elem.value.length) + " " 
                              + ("Decompressed Value: " + _plain + " Size: " 
                              + _plain.length);
    };

    compress.addEventListener("click", compress_string);
    decompress.addEventListener("click", decompress_string);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ov6nwLak/

```js
$.getScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imaya/zlib.js/master/bin/zlib.min.js")

var elem = document.getElementById("input_value")
    , elemLabel = document.getElementById("zlsize")
    , compress = document.getElementById("compress")
    , decompress = document.getElementById("decompress")
    , b64map = []
    , _b64encoded
    , b64encoded
    , _string
    , string
    , _plain
    , compressData;
    elem.value = "<xml><username>myusername</username><password>mypassword</password></xml>";
    function compress_string () {
        string = elem.value;
        _string = [].slice.call(string).map(function (value, key) {
            return value.charCodeAt(0)
        });
        var deflate = new Zlib.Deflate(_string);
        var compressed = deflate.compress();
        for (var i = 0; i < compressed.length; i++) {
            b64map.push([compressed[i]
                , window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(escape(compressed[i])))])
        };
        _b64encoded = b64map.map(function (value, key) {
            return value[1]
        });
        b64encoded = _b64encoded.join("");
        elem.value = b64encoded;
        elemLabel.innerText = ("Size of sample is: " 
                              + string.length) + " " + ("Compressed Value: " 
                              + b64encoded + " Size: " + b64encoded.length)
    };
    
    function decompress_string () {
        string = elem.value;
        elem.value = "";
        compressData = _b64encoded.map(function (value, key) {                      
            return new RegExp(value).test(string) ? b64map[key][0] : null
        });
        
        compressData = new Uint8Array(compressData);
        var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressData);
    
        var plain = inflate.decompress();
        b64map = b64encoded = [];
        _plain = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < plain.length; i++) {
            _plain += String.fromCharCode(plain[i])
        };
        elem.value = _plain;
        elemLabel.innerText = ("Size of compressed string is: " 
                              + elem.value.length) + " " 
                              + ("Decompressed Value: " + _plain + " Size: " +         
                              _plain.length);
    };
    
    compress.addEventListener("click", compress_string);
    decompress.addEventListener("click", decompress_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<input type="text" id="input_value" />
<button id="compress">compress</button>
<button id="decompress">decompress</button>
<br />
<label id="zlsize"></label>
```